# Jupyter Notebook Extensions Fail to Load

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in virtual box with a recent anaconda install. I installed jupyter notebooks using conda. I have followed all of the documentation that I can find online to install notebook extensions but they fail to load with the error messages listed below. The first error is from the jupyter notebook app running in a terminal and the second error is in the chrome java console. Notice that I cannot post this question with this many hyperlinks so I remove the "p" from "http" in my error messages.

> [W 07:02:06.451 NotebookApp] 404 GET
>   /nbextensions/python-markdown.js?v=20150904070147 (127.0.0.1) 8.47ms
>   referer=htt://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb
>
> htt://localhost:8888/nbextensions/python-markdown.js?v=20150904070147
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

To detail my installation method: I cloned the git repository `[IPython-notebook-extensions][1]` and used the command `jupyter-nbextension install python-markdown` inside the `IPython-notebook-extensions/usability/` folder. I then enabled the extension with `jupyter-nbextension enable python-markdown`. I ran these commands as superuser as well.

After this failed I installed this extension inside python (from the usability/ directory of the repository) using:

```
import notebook
notebook.install_nbextension('python-markdown',user=True)
E=notebook.nbextensions.EnableNBExtensionApp()
E.enable_nbextension('python-markdown')
```

I also tried this as the superuser without the parameter `user=True`.

I have confirmed that the files copied to both `/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/python-markdown` and `~/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/python-markdown`. The extension is enabled in the ~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json file. Finally, I also deleted the chromium and mozilla cache (by deleting the folders in the `~/.cache` directory) multiple times while trying this.

Comment: Is this really a programming question? Seems more suitable for [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) or maybe [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Solved here: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/issues/282. The ~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json file must be edited to use `python-markdown/main` instead of `python-markdown`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved here: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/issues/282. The ~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json file must be edited to use `python-markdown/main` instead of `python-markdown`.

Answer (score 1):

More generally this kind of error can also happen after you've upgraded Jupyter/Python/etc and some of the extensions are not supported by your updates. You can then just disable them from the **Nbextensions** configuration tab - you may find that they're the extensions that are shown as incompatible - which can be disabled by ticking the 'disable configuration for nbextensions without explicit compatibility' checkbox.